# Why do some military aircraft carry two datalink pods?

Tags: military, fa-18, data-link

I was taking a look at pictures of the [SLAM-ER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGM-84H/K_SLAM-ER) when I noticed an F/A-18C carrying two AWW-13 datalink pods on its left wing. Why carry a second one? Does it increase signal strength or something?

[image: Image from Wikipedia]
<sup>Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:F-18C_with_SLAM-ER_missile_and_AWW-13_pods_in_flight.jpg</sup>

Comment: This being a question about military aircraft and intel systems, you are unlikely to get accurate factual answers.  As pure speculation though:  reasons may include  Redundancy; extending bandwidth and/or channel count;  Testing, calibration, simulation; training etc.

Comment: Btw, all in all a very peculiar payload on this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That pic is from "the Naval Air Warfare Center, Weapons Division (NAWCWD)"
So, testing and development.

Possible reasons (purely speculative):

1. Testing capability/performance from the 2 different wing stations.
2. Test/compare different software configs in each.
3. Ferry one to somewhere else.